# Error STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_PATH when running qt executables through developer studio

Tags: c++, qt4

I have searched and found no answer to this

I have a weird problem when running executables through developer studio (2008): a basic 'hello world' exe works OK when created through the usual dev studio project creation mechanism, but when trying to run a library based program the software crashes with STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_PATH. The program uses Qt and zlib behind the scenes and is written in C++, but (as far as I'm aware) is not dependent on any particular network locations on initialisation; we do have Sophos installed on the PC too.

The weird thing is that one cant even step into the main: the program fails well before this with the error. If we plug the network in, it starts up just fine ... The odd thing is this only occurs on a specific 64 bit Windows 7 machine.

Does anyone have any tips as to how to trace where the issue is? We've tried tracking using procmon but it is not very revealing; no obvious failures up to the point where the program crashes.

Answer (score 0):

We have now figured out the answer. It transpired that there were 2 issues:

Firstly a wrapper .bat script that was launching developer studio was setting the PATH environment variable: a location in this path was being specified using a UNX style path (e.g. \\a\location\somewhere) rather than a mapped drive. The executables were not actually using this location but when the network was unplugged this it seems that this was disrupting things from dev studio

This, in tandem with a network configuration error on the PC, meant that deep down in the runes, *something* was failing.

So - advice if you see such an error

1. Check your PATH and make sure it is sensible
2. Look in your PC's configuration logs, and see if you can see any networking issues

...

Comment: Just an FYI: `\\a\location\somewhere` is more properly known as a UNC path - it doesn't really have anything to do with UNIX.